# markdownでリモートサーバにある画像の表示と文章のpdf出力がしたい

Tags: vscode, markdown, pandoc

#### 概要

markdownにリモートサーバ内の画像を表示することは可能でしょうか?
また、可能であるならばどのような表記をすればよいでしょうか?

#### 詳細

ローカルにあるmarkdownファイルにリモートのファイルサーバにある画像ファイルを表示させ、pandocを使ってpdfファイルにエクスポートしようとしています。

```
![サンプル](file://image-server/path-to-image/sample.PNG)
```

上記のようにファイルパスを記述してもVSCodeのプレビュー画面には画像は表示されず、pandocとlatexでpdfにエクスポートしようとしても、下記のようなエラーメッセージが表示されます

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'file://image-server/path-to-image/sample.PNG': InvalidUrlException "file://image-server/path-to-image/sample.PNG" image with description.
```

VSCodeの編集画面のほうで、URL部分をマウスオーバーしたときに表示される「リンク先を表示」をクリックすると表示したい画像がVSCode内に表示されます

#### 期待する動作

1. VSCodeのプレビュー画面にリモートサーバにある画像が表示される
2. pandocとlatexを使ってpdfにエクスポートしたとき、pdfファイルにリモートサーバにある画像が表示される

#### 環境

OS: Windows10 (ローカル及びリモートサーバの両方)
エディタ: VSCode 1.43.2
pandoc/latex: [k1LoW/docker-alpine-pandoc-ja](https://github.com/k1LoW/docker-alpine-pandoc-ja) コンテナのlatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) はローカルのファイルシステム上にあるファイルを参照するためのものです。

オンラインにあるファイルを表示するためには他の適切なプロトコルを指定してください。典型的には `https://` です。

SSH で接続できるサーバーであれば、手元で試していませんが `ssh://` を使った URI によるアクセスも可能かもしれません。ただ、普通はそうはせずにローカルに画像ファイルもダウンロードした上で作業するか、Markdown ファイルも SSH 先に置いて VS Code のリモート開発機能を使って作業するか、にしそうです。というのも `ssh://` を使った URI はユーザー情報を含みうる関係上複数人で使いまわしにくいからです。